# Number of arguments passed to Python's pow

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a reason why Python's built-in `pow` allows 3 arguments, but `math.pow` allows only 2?

Of course we could lazily say, "because that's how it's designed".

But does anyone know the reason behind this design decision?

**Edit:**

To clarify, I understand what the difference is, but I'm wondering why we need both. Why not just have the the 3 argument built-in `pow`.

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate. I'm not asking about what the differences are. I just want to know why we need both of them. Is there a reason to not always use the built-in function?

Comment: I haven't benchmarked it, but I'd imagine that `math.pow` is more efficient since it only handles floats (and calls the underlying C libraries), while built-in `pow` is more versatile, but necessarily less efficient since it has to look up the `__pow()__` (or `__rpow()__` and/or `__lpow()__` as needed) methods in its parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Code comments say this:

> Equivalent to `x**y` (with two arguments) or `x**y % z` (with three
>   arguments)
>
> Some types, such as ints, are able to use a more efficient algorithm
>   when invoked using the three argument form.

Comment: I understand that, but then why not always use the built-in `pow`. Are there cases where it's less efficient?